# Ошибка при форматировании времени

Tags: java, android, время

Пытаюсь получить текущее время

```
Date date = new Date();

CharSequence date1 = DateFormat.format("HHmm", date);
```

И дальше превратить в int значение, в итоге при присвоении int переменной выходит ошибка, потому что часы не отображаются вместо них так и остается HH. Код ошибки:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "HH26"
>                             at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
>                             at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
>                             at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
>                             at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:332)
>                             at tat.example.ildar.seer.Main_Activity$MyLocationListener.onLocationChanged(Main_Activity.java:904)
>                             at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport._handleMessage(LocationManager.java:257)
>                             at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport.access$000(LocationManager.java:186)
>                             at android.location.LocationManager$ListenerTransport$1.handleMessage(LocationManager.java:202)
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5319)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
>                             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: В классе `java.text.DateFormat` нет метода `format` с приведенными Вами типами аргументов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас какой-то странный способ форматирования. Вот такой - сработает:

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
String string = sdf.format(date);
```

А вот в одну строку просто так:

```
String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm").format(new Date());
```

Потом в число превратить можно так, как показано в комментах ниже:

```
int dateInt = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm").format(new Date()));
```

Comment: символ ":" в шаблоне лишний - с ним вылетает NumberFormatException.

Comment: @EvgenOrlovsky, если честно, то я не понял что вы хотите сказать.

Comment: @EvgenOrlovsky, Если его убрать, то этот способ тоже будет работать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб присмотритесь к вопросу - автор не в строку результат хочет а в число. причем конкретно в int.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, ТС вот такое хочет: `int dateInt = Integer.parseInt(new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm").format(new Date()));`.

Comment: @post_zeew, хм, точно) Добавил в ответ)

Comment: Только вот с SimpleDateFormat проблема, пишет что он поддерживается только с API Level 24

Comment: @ildar1989, Вы импортируете не тот `SimpleDateFormat`, который нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо за такое бурное обсуждение, попробую применить  ваши примеры НО, самое интересное что на 5 устройствах из 6 мой код работал, не работал только на одном. Вот что странно. Ну и подставив вместо HH в шаблоне kk все прекрасно заработало, хотя много где встречал шаблоны формата времени и HH и KK. Но ни то ни другое не помогало.

```
Date date = new Date();

CharSequence date1 = DateFormat.format("kkmm", date);
```